# Add value per mesh to UV coordinates

Tags: python

I am trying to add additional data to a bunch of individual meshes that look like this in the hierarchy:

[image]

My goal is to from Sweep.001 to Sweep.00n, add 1-n as a UV2 value. I want to do this so that I can procedurally animate in the meshes with a shader animation, one at a time.

Any idea how I can do this? If I can somehow get the number 001, 002, etc... as an integer in a geometry node, I could definitely make it work!

I think the other way would possible be to use python to add data per-vertex.

Comment: Hello and welcome! This is definitely a task for Python. ...with Geometry Nodes you won't get anywhere here.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by *add 1-n as a UV2 value*. can you give an example of this logic? like *Sweep.016* will become *Sweep.XXX*, where XXX in this case is what value? From your logic it sounds like n+(1-n)=1. which means everything becomes overwritten to *Sweep.001*. Please edit your post to give more details of the logic and some expected example results.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie i believe the OP simply means _from 1 to n_ when writing 1-n (not _1 minus n_).

Comment: @taiyo that’s right! Thanks, maybe should have used better notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I got you right, but this script will add a second UV layer and place the number `XXX` from `Sweep.XXX` into the UV vectors. The script assumes all objects under `Null.001` have the string format `<whatever>.<number>`:

```
import bpy

for child in bpy.data.objects['Null.001'].children:
    
    # get the number from the naming suffix
    number = int(child.name.split('.')[1])

    # add new uv layer
    uv2_layer = child.data.uv_layers.new(name='UV2')

    # set the number in the uvs
    for i in range(len(uv2_layer.uv)):
        uv2_layer.uv[i].vector = (number, number)
```

This will give for example for a plane object `Plane.042`:

```
# uv layer 1
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000)>
<Vector (1.0000, 0.0000)>
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000)>
<Vector (0.0000, 1.0000)>

# uv layer 2
<Vector (42.0000, 42.0000)>
<Vector (42.0000, 42.0000)>
<Vector (42.0000, 42.0000)>
<Vector (42.0000, 42.0000)>
```

Comment: also for performance could use `foreach_set` with an array created with `np.full`